# How to retrieve Solr documents having at least 2 numFound with grouping

Tags: solr, grouping

I'm working with Solr and grouping (field collapsing) function.

The request I want to do is the following : get only documents having the "rating" field, and having **at least** 2 documents in the result[@name='doclist'] node.

The request :

```
/select/?q=rating:[* TO *]&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&group=true&group.field=HashKey&group.ngroups=true
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is built-in. Field collapsing is pretty new to Solr, and this seems like a reasonable feature request, so you might try adding it at the [Solr JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR)

Comment: Eh, I filed an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3152)

Comment: Can you phrase it as a facet query? Facets have a `mincount` feature

Comment: Very good idea aitchnyu, it works ! @beerbajay : thanks a lot, really !

Comment: Any idea why this is not added to SOLR yet ?